# Linux Bash Script unhiding files in the directory

Tags: linux, bash, hidden-files

Am trying to make a script to unhide files in the directory with parameter --unhide but it is not working. May you help me? Here is my part of the code.

```
for i in `ls -1`
do
    if [ -f $i ] || [ -d $i ]
    then
        if [ `echo $i | cut -c1` == "." ]
        then
            mv $i ${i#.}
        fi
    fi
done
```

Thanks!

And how about unhide then i write --unhide file1 file2?

```
elif [ $1 = --unhide ] && [ ! $2 = --all ]
then
for i in $@
do
if [ -f $i ] || [ -d $i ]
then
if [ `echo $i | cut -c1` == "." ]
then
mv $i ${i#.}
fi
fi
done
```

Its easy then we have not hidden files, then parameter name is the same name with the file name. But how to check hidden files? I tried to write --unhide .file1 .file2 but script only unhides .file1 and .file2 not.

Comment: I imagine that the particular issue you're seeing is because `ls -1` doesn't include hidden files by default, but mattias has a much more robust way of doing the same thing.

Comment: If you don't believe that using `ls` for this job is intrinsically broken, try testing with some filenames that include spaces... or, worse, newlines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So basically what you are asking for is a script that rename files within a directory, where the files start with a '.'?

Something like the following should work

```
GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
for file in .*; do
   mv -n "$file" "${file#.}"
done
```

Comment: I would, for test purposes, do `echo $file` before running the full `mv -n ` thingie though.. to be sure not to do anything stupid.

Comment: No need to export `GLOBIGNORE`.

Comment: @YannVernier: On OSX I get the '..' and '.' counted without that line. So that is why I included it. I kind of hope he dont try to rename those :) But in some way you are right, it will still work without the GLOBIGNORE.

Comment: They're not symlinks (but the only allowed directory hardlinks), and I just meant you didn't need to export it, not that you shouldn't set it.

Comment: @YannVernier: You're right, edited my comment regarding "symlink".

Comment: Oh i found a fail on my own code. LS -1 dont see hidden files, so i fixed with LS -A -1 and now it is working correctly :)

Comment: @user3168731: Oh good, but maybe you should consider using my solution any way, less lines to care about. And while you're at it, I dont mind you accepting the answer :)

Comment: @mattias, Yann isn't telling you you don't need to _set_ `GLOBIGNORE`, but that you don't need to _export_ it. Just `GLOBIGNORE='.:..'` with no `export` will have the same effect, but fewer side effects.

Comment: @user3168731, `ls` is the wrong tool for the job, even with `-a`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

this is what I come up with

```
ls -a | awk '{ if ($1 ~/^\..*txt$/) print $1,substr($1,2)}'| xargs -n2 mv
```